# Are variadic generics possible in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Is it possible to make a method or function in Java which could take `List<T>` where T can also be a `List<V>`... and so on until finally `T` is `Integer` and we have `List<Integer>` which gets converted to a `List<Double>`?

For example, `List<Integer>` gets converted into `List<Double>` and `List<List<Integer>>` gets converted into `List<List<Double>>`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a recursive function which checks type `T` of `List<T>`. Recursion stops once the type is not inherited from `List`. Then use streams.

**UPDATE**

On a second thought, it looks like due to [type erasure in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens) it is not possible.

My original idea was to use a code like below. It's not prefect (nasty casts) but it is syntactically correct, however it looks like there is no syntactically correct way to call those functions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    private <T> List<Double> foo(List<T> some) {
        return some.stream().map(item -> Double.class.cast(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private <T> List foo(List<T> some, Class<T> klass) {
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(klass)) {
            List result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T item : some) {
                result.add(foo(List.class.cast(item), item.getClass()));
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return foo(some);
        }
    }
}
```